# How to execute/apply extra logic when xcm call delivered and deposit is succeed? or register callback?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, xcm, substrate-parachain-template, orml

I want to execute extra logic when xcm call deliver and deposit succeed.
I can pass extra parameters in beneficiary MultiLocation with a description what todo next.
I have a MultiLocation
MultiLocation {
parents: 0, interior: X4(
PalletInstance(pallet_id),
AccountId32{ id, network: None },
GeneralIndex(chain_id),
AccountId32{ id: _, network: None } ) } => id,

This is beneficiary in xcm `(reserve_transfer_assets xcmPallet)`

I want to use AccountId32 from MultiLocation to send received xcm tokens on that account  but also apply/execute extra logic depends on other parameters as PalletInstance and GeneralIndex.

I want your advise.
Is it reasonable approach?

I have this Location into Account Id convertor

```
pub struct AccountId32Batch<AccountId>(PhantomData<AccountId>);
impl<AccountId: From<[u8; 32]> + Into<[u8; 32]> + Clone>
    xcm_executor::traits::Convert<MultiLocation, AccountId> for AccountId32Batch<AccountId>
{
    fn convert(location: MultiLocation) -> Result<AccountId, MultiLocation> {
        let id = match location {
            MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X4(
                PalletInstance(_), 
                AccountId32{ id, network: None }, 
                GeneralIndex(_), 
                AccountId32{ id: _, network: None } ) } => id,
            _ => return Err(location),
        };
        Ok(id.into())
    }

    fn reverse(who: AccountId) -> Result<MultiLocation, AccountId> {
        Err(who)
    }
}
```

I want to execute extra logic when deposit succeeded.
There is no `on_success_callback` in MultiCurrency. only on_failed
https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library/blob/master/xcm-support/src/currency_adapter.rs#L148-L161

So i will create wrapper for MultiCurrency to pass callback function that will be executed when deposit is succeed.

What do you think about this approach?
Did you ever see any similar behaviour that apply extra logic on deposit/withdraw success?